# Redirecting HTTPS

Tags: iis, web-server, https, forwarding, 301-redirect

We built a site for a client to advertise a new block of apartments they had built.  The apartments have now all been sold so we have been asked to forward the domain to another domain until there is a future use for it.

We have tried to do this by setting up a 301 redirect on our server - this works great for HTTP requests (both with and without WWW) but HTTPS requests fail.  Can anyone offer us any tips?

here are the 2 web config files we have tried:

**WEB CONFIG 1:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

 <rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Redirect to http" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="(/\w*[/ | \w]+\.aspx)" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
    </rule>

  </rules>
</rewrite>

<location path="index.html">
    <system.webServer>
        <httpRedirect destination="https://WEBFORWARDINGDOMAIN.co.uk/" />
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```

**WEB CONFIG 2**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <configuration>
   <location path="index.html">
    <system.webServer>
        <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="https://WEBFORWARDINGDOMAIN.co.uk/" childOnly="true" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
 </configuration>
```

Comment: For SEO purpose you should use a 302 redirect here, not a 301.

Comment: Have you tried redirecting to a https site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of your configurations are applying the HTTP Redirect on the index.html file directly.  This effectively causes the redirect to only happen if someone goes directly to http://yoursite.co.uk/index.html or https://yoursite.co.uk/index.html.

Try the following in your root web.config and take out the IIS URL Rewrite rule that you have.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="https://WEBFORWARDINGDOMAIN.co.uk/" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks @Tim Liston, I've changed the web config to the above but still no luck i'm afraid.  its doing the same thing (site cant be reached error with https)

Comment: Do you have an HTTPS binding on the site with a valid certificate?

Comment: Thanks @tim a combination of certificate and the above config did the trick